# Hello, how to use stdClass in codeigniter 4?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

```php
$data['trafik'] = new stdClass;
```

This shows me error:

> Class 'App\Controllers\stdClass' not found

Comment: As it's in a namespace, you will need `\stdClass`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your current code is within a namespace, you can access stdClass from the root namespace like this:

```
$data['trafik'] = new \stdClass;
```

Comment: fantastic !! thank you bro